# Not able to boot from the HDD on which i have installed win7, able to boot from secondary HDD

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have two HDD (500Gb n 1Tb) recently i have installed win 7 from UI to my HDD-1Tb (when i have logged in from another HDD(500Gb) as win7) Now the problem is, the installation got successfull in my new HDD(1TB), but when i am selection this 1TB HDD for booting nothing is happening. And when I am selecting my old HDD(500GB) during boot-up i am able to login to my newly installed windows7 in 1TB HDD.

So the problem is, I am able to bootup my newly installed win7 of 1TB HDD from my old 500GB HDD(not from my 1TB HDD)

Can anyone help me solve my this problem ASAP. Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please clarify your question. I was going to attempt to corect the grammar but I wasn't even able to understand the question in order to do that.  Your last sentence makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: sorry...for this wrong english(written in hurry)
I was logged in from win7 that was installed on my 500GB HDD, from there I started installing win7 to my new 1TB HDD with 150GB partition in that.
Now the problem is that when I start my PC(while bootup process) and select my 1TB HDD from boot menu then windows is not loading, but at the same place when I select my 500GB HDD it shows two 'win7' option on which one of them at the top is for loading the windows i just installed in 1TB HDD.
Now, If I want to format my 500GB HDD then how can i load the win7 present in 1TB HDD.

Comment: @Ramhound please reply !

Comment: Once you make the required modifications to your question I will attempt to answer. If that doesn't happen then I cannot answer your question.   You being in a hurry is not a valid excuse.

Comment: ok @Ramhound, I have done modification to my Ques, now you can take your time to answer it.
thanks

Comment: Its the same revision.  You have made no modifications to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to remove both hard disks from your mother board and only plug one hard disk one at a time. Let's see whether you can boot from both hard disks. If you want to format the 1TB disk, just plug only that and try to boot.

Comment: If i plug only my 1TB hdd, then it's not booting.
and also I am not able to boot up win7 from USB now...so is there any software through which I could run in my 1TB hdd and that will sort this problem by changing the bootmgr or similar thing

Thanks

Comment: So can you boot from 500 GB hard? [I mean by only plugging the 500 hard to the computer? not both] I think the problem occurs because you had not installed win7 in 1TB by boot from a CD. Instead, you installed it by logging into win7 in 500gb. And if you want to boot from a USB, first make sure boot from USB is enabled in BIOS.

Comment: Also try to plug the hard disk which you want to boot from, to the SATA port 0. It might help. Unfortunately if none of these worked, try to boot from a ubuntu cd and backup your data. Then do a clean installation of win7 again.

Comment: ok..I'll try connecting it to sata port 0...get back to you.
thanks